# How to get the Shared Connection URL in Guacamole 1.0 Programmatically

Tags: guacamole

I'm new to Guacamole and I need to get a shared connection URL for every new connection. For reasons, we don't have the REST API available. In Guacamole 1.0, how do I generate the shared connection url using the Java api? I want to have a url that I can send to a user so they can share an existing connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get sharing profiles using Java API. First, you need to make sure you are using an authentication extension that supports sharing. The database extensions under `guacamole-auth-jdbc` supports sharing.

To get sharing profiles, you need to call the following API:

```
GET <base-url>/api/session/tunnels/<extension-id>/activeConnection/connection/sharingProfiles?token=<token>
```

where:

- `base-url` is the application base url
- `extension-id` is the ID of the particular extension (it may be mysql or sqlserver etc...). You can get this ID in the AuthenticationProvider.java source file in the extension code.
- `token` is access token, you can get one using `api/tokens` call; the token should be the first thing to get, as it is used for all API calls.

The JS example for using sharing API you can find in the `guacamole/src/main/webapp/app/rest/services/tunnelService.js` file, and for getting token in the `guacamole/src/main/webapp/app/auth/service/authenticationService.js` file. Converting example from JS to Java shouldn't be a problem, those files are simple service that just use the Java API.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. The URL is created in the existing client's JavaScript and the API, so if you don't use those, you can't create a share URL. You will need to modify the Java code in the client to create a shared connection.